# Create window-specific rule in KDE4

Tags: linux, google-chrome, kde, kwin

KDE 4 has a feature 'ElectricBorders' which maximizes a window when it's dragged towards the upper edge of the screen. I can disable it globally by editing ~/.kde4/share/config/kwinrc

```
[Windows]
ElectricBorderMaximize=false
```

How can I disable this feature for a specific window? I find this extremely annoying in google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use GUI to make window-specific rules:

right-click on window title:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have the option to disable ElectricBorders from the GUI tool.